# Remove class when toggle is collapsed

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove a class from body when `slideToggle` is collapsed. Right now it is removing class when body is clicked and adding class again when menu is `slidetoggle` is open.

Behavior demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7awLhv9t/1/

When body is clicked it collapse the menu and remove class from body but when we click on menu item to collapse it doesn't remove class from body.

I tried `if ($(".menu-item").hasClass("active")) { $( "body" ).removeClass( "menu-is-active" );` but it break the code in the worse way.

Answer (score 3):

To make this work you firstly need to stop the click on the `a` elements from propagating up the DOM. This is due to the `click` handler you've also placed on the `document` itself to remove the styling when closing all the menus.

Secondly, you can use `toggleClass()` to only apply the class to the `body` when a menu is active. Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".nav-menu a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    $(".nav-menu a").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.sub-menu').slideUp('fast');

    $("body").toggleClass("menu-is-active", $('.nav-menu li.active').length != 0);
  });
});

$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".menu-item");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $(".sub-menu").slideUp("fast").not(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    $("body").removeClass("menu-is-active");
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

body.menu-is-active {
  background: #fdff76;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li>
    <a herf="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a herf="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a herf="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a herf="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a herf="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a herf="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a herf="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you only added `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent the click behavior repeat?

Comment: Great. Everything working fine except when we click on the menu item in the sub-menu. It make the menu to collapse but again class is not removing from the body.

Comment: That's because it's caught by the `$(".nav-menu a")` selector. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Never mind. i Solved it by adding `$( ".nav-primary .sub-menu a" ).click(function() {
$( "body" ).removeClass( "menu-is-active" )
});
`